# When diagnosing a memory leak in a .NET application, what does it mean if the working set is large but the data on the heap is small?

Tags: asp.net, .net, linux, .net-core, memory-leaks

I have an application running in Kubernetes that seems to have a memory leak, after running for some time Kubernetes will scale out to the max count of instances, and terminate them when they reach the max memory.

I have installed some profiling tools and found that the 'Working set' is large, taking up 1.7gb, but when I open a dump of the memory I see that the application is only using about 44mb. What can I do next to see where all the memory is going?

[image]

Comment: Likely to be either an unmanaged leak (bitmaps, handles or `malloc`), or a CLR leak like something involving dynamic assemblies (`XmlSerializer` or other serialization which generates code on the fly). I suggest you use more detailed profilers, try Ants for instance.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this? I'm experiecing something similar: NET 5 web api in a linux docker container in Kubernetes and the memory keeps growing until it restarts but a heap dump shows only about 40 MB of memory.

Comment: Same issue on my side. AKS + .NET 6 Console App

Comment: Same issue .NET 6 ASP.Net core project